# system of equations SciPy

Tags: python, scipy

I would like to solve such a system of equations:

```
21.7424698112 = A + B*2^{-x} 
22.4531418345 = A + B*3^{-x} 
23.8033967265 = A + B*4^{-x}
```

I wrote a script to find A, B and x variables:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import root

def your_funcs(X):

    A, B, x = X

    f = [21.7424698112-A-B*(1/2**x),
         22.4531418345-A-B*(1/3**x),
         23.8033967265-A-B*(1/4**x)]

    return f

sol = root(your_funcs, [1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
print(sol.x)
```

This approach leads to the following solution:

```
[ 22.66633613 -50.69139062 105.89893632]
```

I checked the solution and turned out that these values do not satisfy above equations. What am I doing wrong? Should I be aware of something?

Comment: You are missing negative signs plus the constants are different in your question and in your code

Comment: @Sheldore You're right. I corrected my post. The solution is still wrong.

Comment: I get the same answer as @joni below and the solution fulfills all three equations simultaneously. What is wrong? You are *still* missing negative signs before the constants in your equations in the function. Do you realize that?

Comment: @Sheldore, the signs are correct now.

Comment: The solver needs a better initial guess.  It works with, for example, `sol = root(your_funcs, [5.0, 1.0, -1.0])`.  The solution is then `[21.42987711,  0.04116848, -2.92467199]`.

Comment: FYI: In the future, always check `sol.success` before using `sol.x`. When `root` is run with the initial guess `[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]`, `sol.success` is False, and `sol.message` is `'The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the \n improvement from the last ten iterations.'`.

Comment: @Warren Weckesser Thank you for your help!